# WARNING: appId set, but please call setLaunchOptions(launchOptions) to complete OneSignal init

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, onesignal

I have tried setting up `onesignal` plugin for my ionic project. But, when running in Xcode, I am seeing this warning.

```
WARNING: appId set, but please call setLaunchOptions(launchOptions) to complete OneSignal init!
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onesignal 3.0.0-beta1 version is not working, downgraded and all clear

Answer (score 0):

I also had to deal with that mistake.
**setLaunchOptions** is automatically inserted by the framework (cordova, ionic etc), so if that error appears it means that something went wrong.
Mine was a certificate error, try to check your certificate and app ID of your app on ios.